# Function that reformats the date of birth. Also remove “leading zero” on the day using awk

Tags: awk

I have assignment in awk I have to create script that does the following task:**
Print all lines where the email address contains more than 40 characters. Then create a function that reformats the date of birth. Also remove “leading zero” on the day.

**Input**

```
firstname,lastname,city,born,phone,email
Joseph,Långström,Upplands Väsby och Sollentuna,1997-11-02,555403172,joseph.langstrom@upplands_vasby_och_sollentuna.se
Salma,Helin,Hällaryd,2002-07-03,555674792,salma.helin@hallaryd.se
Maximiliam,Ahlstrand,Stångenäs och Rixö,2001-06-03,555914429,maximiliam.ahlstrand@stangenas_och_rixo.se
Sanna,Wahlgren,Torhamn,2004-08-02,555493393,sanna.wahlgren@torhamn.se
```

**The desired output**

```
Joseph 2/nov-1997
Maximiliam 3/jun-2001
```

**Here is how far I got**

```
BEGIN {FS = ","}

NR == 1 { next }

{
    if (length($6) > 40){print $0}
        
}

END {
    print "\n-------------------------------\n"
}
```

**The Result that I am getting**

```
Joseph,Långström,Upplands Väsby och Sollentuna,1997-11-02,555403172,joseph.langstrom@upplands_vasby_och_sollentuna.se
Maximiliam,Ahlstrand,Stångenäs och Rixö,2001-06-03,555914429,maximiliam.ahlstrand@stangenas_och_rixo.se
```

**My Question is**

Then create a function that reformats the date of birth. Also remove “leading zero” on the day.

I am stuck and have no clue how to proceed, If some one can help or guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
length($6) > 40 {
    split($4,d,/-/)
    year  = d[1]
    month = substr("janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec",(d[2]-1)*3+1,3)
    day   = d[3] + 0
    print $1, day "/" month "-" year
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Joseph 2/nov-1997
Maximiliam 3/jun-2001
```

`d[]` is the array created by `split` to hold the date components (see `split()` in the awk manual), `(d[2]-1)*3+1` is creating an index into the string of month name abbreviations before it so `substr()` (again, see the manual) can return that month name abbreviation, and `d[3]+0` is adding `0` to the day number to strip the leading zero during the resulting string->number conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain these for me what this (d[2]-1)*3+1 and d[3] + 0 does. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to explain those statements.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` solution should work

```
awk -F, 'length {gsub(/-/," ");$4=strftime("%d/%b-%Y", mktime($4" 0 0 0"));sub(/0/,"",$4)} NR > 1 { print $1, $4}' input_file
```

`length` - Skip blank lines

`gsub(/-/," ")` - Change format of date for `mktime` to use

`$4=strftime("%d/%b-%Y", mktime($4" 0 0 0"))` - Change date format
**Output**

```
$ awk -F, 'length {gsub(/-/," ");$4=strftime("%d/%b-%Y", mktime($4" 0 0 0"));sub(/0/,"",$4)} NR > 1 { print $1, $4}' input_file

Joseph 2/Nov-1997

Salma 3/Jul-2002

Maximiliam 3/Jun-2001

Sanna 2/Aug-2004
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for time functions.